# Nested If Statement with ssh

Tags: bash, if-statement, ssh

I am attempting to create a script that will A) cycle through a list of IP's and ping them, if successful attempt to log in using known credentials and if successful with that add the host to a list so the actions do not repeat.

This script runs as expected if A) the host is unavailable to ping or B) if it is available and my known credentials work. If it can ping the host but the ssh connection is rejected the script quits instead of using the next variable (or IP). Thanks!

What I have so far:

```
while read p; do
  ping -c1 -t1 $p
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p $PW ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$USR"@"$p" </dev/null "
    scutil --get ComputerName" | tee -ai $WORKING

    MACHINE=$(head -n 1 $WORKING)

    if grep -Fxq $MACHINE "$FULL"
    then
      echo $MACHINE has been worked on already

    else
      echo $MACHINE has not been worked on
      echo $MACHINE >> $FULL
      rm -rf $WORKING
    fi

  else
    echo ping fail
  fi
done </iprange.txt
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: Why is it not cycling to the next variable when the ssh connection is denied? If i remove the nested if loop it works as expected

Comment: What is an "if loop"? Oh, and please post a [mcve]. You example is not minimal.

Comment: Are you running this with the shell's `-e` option set?

Comment: As I think others may have answered your question, just a point, you can put your ping straight into the if as it too tests the outcome of commands :-      if ping -c1 -t1 "$p"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is, but it looks like your `ssh` command is probably eating your `STDIN` from your `while read` loop.

Either try changing which FD your `read` command is reading from:

```
while read -u 9 -r p ; do
  echo "$p"
done 9< /iprange.txt
```

Or try using the `-n` argument to your `ssh` command which redirects `STDIN` from `/dev/null` (prevents reading of your `STDIN` from `/iprange.txt`).